# British citizen and non-EU visitor visa marriage

Tags: visas, uk, legal, weddings

I (a British citizen with full UK passport) and my fiancee (a Chinese citizen) plan to get married in the UK. She currently has a type C visitor multiple-entry visa allowing her to visit the UK until 2020.

Is her visa sufficient for us to get married or will she need to apply for a [marriage visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa)? We both currently reside in Hong Kong and do not plan to stay in the UK after the wedding.

Comment: She has to apply for a Marriage Visitor Visa. Otherwise she may be accused of migration by deception and deported.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid your answer-in-a-comment does not seem to agree with the answer at [Does a US citizen, lawfully in the UK, need a specific visa to get married there?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/106014/19400); can you explain the difference?

Comment: @phoog: To discourage fake marriages and misuse of the associated privileges the rules are different country by country. A chinese citizen is under general suspicion of trying to illegally take residence in the UK. This be may sound discriminatory and in fact is, but immigration regulation are like that as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is: she has to apply for a Marriage Visitor Visa. Otherwise she may be accused of migration by deception and deported. An authoritative explanation can be found here: https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships/foreign-national

Additional documents will be required. You are advised to contact the local council at minimum 2 months ahead and ask for details! [Rules](https://www.gov.uk/marriages-civil-partnerships/documents-to-take-to-the-register-office)

If your future wife is divorced in China you will have fun, lots of it. To the point that it is maybe advisable to marry in HK and register the marriage later in the UK.